# C# and Reading Large XML Files

Tags: c#, xml

I know, I know this has been done to death; Im just posting a question to see if this solution is still relevant since now we have .NET 4 and newer

[This link](https://bratched.com/en/2010/05/19/linq-to-xml-and-reading-large-xml-files/) explain a simple way to read large XML files and it implements Linq. I quite like this and just want a simple answer/s to state if this is still relevant or are there better implementations in newer .NET code.

Comment: As you can see in the site you linked, it's mentioned *LINQ to XML*, which I think is one of the easiest and fastest way (in terms of writing code) to read and write xml documents. Infact LINQ was implemented in *C# 3.0* and it a powerful way to write query over collections and data source.

Comment: @Fuex Using LINQ to XML out of the box will load the full document into memory so although it is easy to *write* querying code, it doesn't make the performance any quicker. The example linked to however, uses `XmlReader` in conjunction with LINQ so should work quite well.

Comment: @James Yes, I agree with you. Load the entire data into memory becomes a problem when dealing with large files and will condition the performances of the queries. So use `XmlReader` in conjunction with *LINQ* is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks guys good info, I will decide to use this method. Thanks heaps for the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer to this question hasn't changed in .NET 4 - for best performance you should still be using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) as it *streams* the document instead of loading the full thing into memory.

The code you refer to uses `XmlReader` for the actual querying so should be reasonably quick on large documents.

Answer (score 12):

If it seems like this:

```
<root>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    ...
</root>
```

you can read file with `XmlReader` and each 'item' open with `XmlDocument` like this:

```
reader.ReadToDescendant("root");
reader.ReadToDescendant("item");

do
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadOuterXml());
    XmlNode item = doc.DocumentElement;

    // do your work with `item`
}
while (reader.ReadToNextSibling("item"));

reader.Close();
```

In this case, you have no limits on file size.

Comment: @GreenGood, Not correct! I tested this code many times and it work properly. 'reader.ReadToDescendant("item");' seek the first element, 'reader.ReadOuterXml()' read current element and 'reader.ReadToNextSibling("item")' go to next element.

Comment: are it possible to do this which parallel ?

Comment: Also if you do not have spaces in your xml file, after `ReadOuterXml` you should not call `ReadToNextSibling`, because it will skip one item. So you have to check the current position, and if it is at note start, do not call `ReadToNextSibling`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is read it line by line using [XmlReader.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.create.aspx).

```
var reader = XmlReader.Create(filename);
reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
while (reader.Read())
{
    // your code here.
}
```

Comment: Isn't `XmlTextReader` deprecated?

Comment: the documentation linked doesn't say deprecated on it anywhere so I'd guess its not...

Comment: @user1096188 Thanks for pointed out, I have updated the code to use `XmlReader.Create`.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue from last few days. I just **right click** on **project properties** then navigated to **Build tab** and select option **Any CPU**, tick **uncheck** option **Prefer 32 Bit** and save it before to run your app, it helped me. I have attached snapshot of the same.
[image]