# Reading an xml file 50 lines at a time

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, xmlreader

Currently trying to make a method to read in XML files at the moment 50 lines at a time this will be increased to allow larger files to be used in the program.

At the moment i am trying to accomplish this with the following code.

```
 List<dataclass.DataRecord> list = new List<dataclass.DataRecord>();
 string filename = "FileLocation"
 XmlDocument testing = new XmlDocument();

 //using (StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(filename))
 using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(filename)))
 {
   while (reader.Read() != null)
   {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
     testing.Load(reader);

     //list.add(line);
     Console.WriteLine(testing);
     //testing.Load(reader);
     }
   }
 }
```

commented lines are just from previous ideas i used to accomplish my goal and the filename has been taken out as i just prefer not to place that online.

Basically at the moment i keep getting the following error:

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

So i dunno if I am:

A. Going about this the right way.

B. Is the only way to fix this error is by surrounding the "testing.load" by "root + /root" tags

hope someone can help thank.

Comment: You should think of XML like a **Tree** rather than a **Flat file** with lines. A line doesn't make sense in XML, you could be cutting a **node** up if you only read 50 "lines". What are you achieving by doing this?

Comment: okay ill give that a look over, I am rather new to doing this.

Comment: to answer you question in what im achieving, I am just trying to load the file gradually rather than all in one go .

Comment: OK, I've added as an answer as you're not supposed to use comments as a communication method and my idea is a bit longer than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I explained in my comment XML consists of **nodes** whereas you are looking at it as though it were a flat-file with lines.

There are a couple of Stackoverflow questions with answers that match what you are trying to do. The real question is **"How can you load a large XML file"**. The answer is to use a stream rather than loading in one big chunk, following on from there you can find lots of resources about using [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx).

**Couple of pointers to other SO articles:**

[C# and Reading Large XML Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931769/c-sharp-and-reading-large-xml-files)

[Reading large XML documents in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671958/reading-large-xml-documents-in-net)

Hope that helps!

Comment: helps alot, just as you posted i was looking at these links as well from a combination of your comment and pyfods answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to load xml into XmlDocument - why not just

```
 XmlDocument testing = new XmlDocument();
 testing.Load(filename);
```

Comment: I know i could just do that but, but the program maybe needed to load very large files, so this method of loading the file in gradually hopefully should be efficient

Answer (score 0):

If your XML file is really big, you're better off using some sort of pull parser (parses tag-by-tag, attribute-by-attribute, etc) rather than DOM parser (loads whole document during parsing, keeps it in memory).