# Read an xml upto the size of 20 mb and assign it to a list of class

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml which is upto 20 mb:

```
<Neighborhood>
<Code LocationID='27767' NeighborhoodName='Broadway-Times Square' Latitude='40.7586' Longitude='-73.988152'/>
<Code LocationID='27767' NeighborhoodName='Midtown East' Latitude='40.755645' Longitude='-73.967428'/>
</Neighborhood>
```

I want to read the xml and create a list of class.

The class is as follows :

```
public class HotelNeighbourhood
{
  public int LocationID { get; set; }
  public string NeighborhoodName { get; set; }
  public float Latitude { get; set; }
  public float Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

I want create a list in a fastest possible manner.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Next time, please be more sensitive about formatting.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Comment: please read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12931769/c-sharp-and-reading-large-xml-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671958/reading-large-xml-documents-in-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468948/in-c-sharp-what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-large-xml-size-of-1gb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want

```
 var query = (from n in xml.Descendants("Code")
              select new HotelNeighbourhood()
              {
                   LocationID = Convert.ToInt32(n.Attribute("LocationID").Value),
                   NeighborhoodName = n.Attribute("NeighborhoodName").Value,
                   Longitude = float.Parse(n.Attribute("Longitude").Value),
                   Latitude = float.Parse(n.Attribute("Latitude").Value)

              }).ToList();
```

Will give you a `List<HotelNeighborhood>`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document), this will work whereas not sure if it is the fastest approach.

Comment: +1. How could I forget about serialization...

Comment: Better than forgetting about Dre.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for [`XmlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) class usage. It's the fastest way to gain read-only access to XML file, especially when the file is big. It reads one element at the time, so you don't need to load whole document at once.

You could also check LINQ to XML. It's more developer-friendly, but unfortunately requires loading whole XML into memory, what could cause problem when file is large.

Answer (score 0):

reader = new XmlTextReader(_XMLUrlPath + "indexNeighbourhood.xml");
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "Code")
                            {
                                HotelNeighbourhood hotelNeighbourhood = new HotelNeighbourhood();
                                hotelNeighbourhood.LocationID = int.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("LocationID").ToString());
                                hotelNeighbourhood.NeighborhoodName = reader.GetAttribute("NeighborhoodName").ToString();
                                hotelNeighbourhood.Latitude = reader.GetAttribute("Latitude").ToString() != string.Empty ? float.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("Latitude").ToString()) : 0;
                                hotelNeighbourhood.Longitude = reader.GetAttribute("Longitude").ToString() != string.Empty ? float.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("Longitude").ToString()) : 0;
                                LstHNeighbourHood.Add(hotelNeighbourhood);
                            }
                        }
                        reader.Close();
                        reader = null;
path